# Not seeing ExtJS grid state cookie during ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, extjs

I have a ExtJS grid with the following:

// Initialize the state manager

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider());
```

// Set the state id

```
stateful:true,    
stateId:'Vehicle-grid',
```

I was able to get the cookie on a normal HTTP request.
When I try to send a jQuery ajax request though I don't see the cookie server-side.
All I see is jsessionid.

What am I missing.

I can paste the whole code if necessary, but I was just wondering if I was missing something fundamental about how this all works.

Thanks,
Ian

PS - On the back end I have this code (grails controller):

```
def allCookies = request.cookies;
for (c in allCookies) {
    println "\n"+c.name+"\n";
}
```

I only get JSESSIONID printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out.

I foolishly didn't realize that the cookie is only set after certain events on the grid are triggered and not upon initialization, has nothing to do with a regular request vs. an ajax request.

Thanks for you help anyway McStretch.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad you found the solution. Go ahead and mark your solution as the accepted one so the question is effectively closed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to send an ajax request with ExtJS, not through jQuery. jQuery has no idea about ExtJS's stateful variables/objects inherently (they are two different javascript libraries), so the cookie would not be handled the way you expect it to. I'm assuming the normal HTTP request you mention was handled by ExtJS, which is why you saw the expected cookie behavior.

Here's an example of how to fire an ajax request with ExtJS:

```
// Basic request
Ext.Ajax.request({
   url: 'foo.php',
   success: someFn,
   failure: otherFn,
   headers: {
       'my-header': 'foo'
   },
   params: { foo: 'bar' }
});
```

More info can be found in the  [API Documentation](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I meant a regular HTTP request, I meant submitting a form normally and refreshing the page (not AJAX). So I don't see why it would matter whether I use ExtJS to do the AJAX call or jQuery. The cookie should be created and stored on the client system right?

Comment: Are you doing a form submit through ExtJS or html? Did you try and use ExtJS's ajax request?

Comment: Originally I was doing a form submit through html. I wanted to make the form AJAX so I started using jQuery. I have not tried using ExtJS. Now when I submit the form all I get returned for cookie name is JSESSIONID.